# Differential bigraded algebra when it is a tensor product of d. graded algebras: Definition of differential

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

So I'm reading "A User's guide to spectral sequences", 2nd ed., of McCleary and there is defined in page 11 the notion of differential bigraded algebra, and then there is the example of the bigraded algebra $A^*\otimes B^*$ that turns to be a differential bigraded algebra by

$$d_{\otimes}(a\otimes b)=d(a)\otimes b +(-1)^{deg (a)}a\otimes d(b)$$

with $$ (a\otimes b)(x \otimes y)= (-1)^{deg(b)+deg(x)}ax\otimes by $$ and

$$ d(ax)=d(a)x+(-1)^{deg(a)}ad(x). $$

The problem I have is on one hand I have (to simplify notation i will ommit "$deg$")

$$ d_{\otimes}((a\otimes b)(x\otimes y))= (-1)^{b+x}d(a)x\otimes by+(-1)^{a+d(b)+x}ax\otimes d(b)y+(-1)^{a+d(x)}ad(x)\otimes by+(-1)^{a}ax\otimes bd(y)$$

if I apply first the differential and, on the other hand, if I apply first the product $d_\otimes$ I get

$$d_{\otimes}((a\otimes b)(x\otimes y))= (-1)^{b+x}d(a)x\otimes by+(-1)^{a+b}ax\otimes d(b)y+(-1)^{a+x+b}ad(x)\otimes by+(-1)^{a}ax\otimes bd(y) $$

which are not the same. Probably it is because I'm making a stupid mistake, but I cannot find it.

Comment: The mistake is in the second line: The sign should be $(-1)^{\operatorname{deg}(b)\operatorname{deg}(x)}$. The general rule of thumb is that you get a minus sign whenever two odd elements change place (this gives you the sign in the first equation since $d$ is odd).

Comment: Thank you so much, @Bertram . As I said it was a stupid mistake. Thank you again and sorry for the inconvenience.